# Plot histogram / curve on time axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have a feeling there is a very simple way of doing this. I'm trying to plot a timeline of a tasks running on an an environment, incl. two plots on the same diagram:

1. the task run-times as a `broken_barh`
2. an overall load curve based on the aggregate of tasks on each time-point (or a histogram), let's say with lower opacity or a line.

In the example there were 6 tasks running (A-F), for various lengths, with different start times. They are plotted exactly as I need (1/), in a gant-like chart, time on the X axis.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

cols=['ID','From','To']

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 736758.993, 736758.995], ['B', 736758.995, 736758.998],
                   ['C', 736758.994, 736758.996], ['D', 736758.996, 736758.997],
                   ['E', 736758.996, 736758.997], ['F', 736758.995, 736758.996]],
                   columns=cols)

df['Diff'] = df['To']-df['From']

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
for i, slice in df.iterrows():
    values = [[slice['From'], slice['Diff']]]
    ax.broken_barh((values), (i-0.4,0.8), color=np.random.rand(3))

ax.xaxis_date()
```

To this I would like to add 2/ a curve, showing the active task count at each time (1 between 23:51-23:52, 2 for 23:52-53 etc., peaking around 23:54)

The problem with this is that I cannot just draw a histogram of the start times, since the different task overlap in time. Do you know a decent way to create such histogram?

Comment: Don't you want to group your data first by ID or do you aim for a [Gantt chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18072543/8881141)?

Comment: I think this question can be improved a lot. Currently the code shows a Gantt chart type of plot, while this is **not at all** what your asking about here. I would remove all about the broken bar stuff because that is what you already know how to do and will not help at all with the envisionned task.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo, the IDs are unique. I did some edits. And I tried to clarify. I need two plots on the same diagram, a gantt-like chart + a curve showing the load. I hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure there are cleaner ways to approach this. Especially the float math problems were pretty annoying, when trying to create the histogram. The first part is a simple one liner, though. Just use, as suggested, `hlines` and increase the `linewidth` to create your bar chart.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 736758.993, 736758.995], ['B', 736758.995, 736758.998],
                   ['C', 736758.994, 736758.996], ['D', 736758.994, 736758.997],
                   ['E', 736758.997, 736758.998], ['F', 736758.995, 736758.999]],
                   columns = ['ID','From','To'])

#create two subplots with shared x axis
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex = True)
#plot1 - Gantt chart for individual IDs
ax1.hlines(df.ID, df.From, df.To, colors = cm.inferno(df.index/len(df)), linewidth = 20)

#plot 2 - make table of time series for each ID - multiply by 1000 to avoid float problems
hist_count = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(np.arange(1000 * row["From"], 1000 * row["To"])), axis = 1)
hist_count = pd.melt(hist_count)["value"].dropna().astype(int)
#find borders for bins 
min_time = hist_count.min(axis = 0)
max_time = hist_count.max(axis = 0)
#plot 2 histogram - add 0.0001 to prevent arbitrary binning due to float problems
ax2.hist(hist_count / 1000 + 0.0001, range = (min_time / 1000, (max_time + 1) / 1000), bins = max_time - min_time + 1)
ax2.xaxis_date()

plt.show()
```

Output from sample data set:
[image]